# Error During Reading XML file

Tags: php, xml, domdocument

I am using following code ...

//define the filename we wish to write to and the url we wish to download from

```
    $filename = 'capital_one.xml';
    $url = "http://feeds.perfb.com/index.php/download?OEMAIL=chirag_gir@visitwembley.co.uk&PX=e90daba5ee2c6fd4d0c344fd61911f33&DISPLAYFORMAT=HEAD&REVERSEMAPXML=yes&PRODUCTDB_ID=294";



 //this creates the file "feed download".xml and takes he contents from the URL and stores them into the file
file_put_contents($filename,file_get_contents($url));

//create instance of XMLReader
    $xmlReader = new XMLReader();

//read in xml file
$xmlReader->open($filename);

//loop to read in data
while($xmlReader->read())
{
         //this initialises the xml parser
         $dom = new DOMDocument();
         $domNode = $xmlReader->expand();
         $element = $dom->appendChild($domNode);
         $domString = utf8_encode($dom->saveXML($element));
         $product = new SimpleXMLElement($domString);

         //read in data
         echo $product_code = $product->product_code;


}
```

I got following error

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DOMNode::appendChild() must be an instance of DOMNode

can you please help me ?

Comment: You need to do some investigation yourself, and tell us what you find. On what line does the error occur? What have you found from doing a search on the error message text? Have you read up on the module's error handling facilities?

Answer (score 1):

If `expand()` doesn't return a `DOMNode`, an error occurred and `FALSE` is returned instead.

Comment: what I have to change in my code please help

Comment: I would suggest adding `error_reporting(-1)` and `ini_set('display_errors', 'On')` at the top to see if any errors were logged.

Comment: Now I got error     Warning: XMLReader::read(): /var/www/visitwembley.co.uk/development/capital_one.xml:86: parser error : xmlParseEntityRef: no name in /var/www/visitwembley.co.uk/development/getxmldata.php on line 33 Warning: XMLReader::read(): Travel & Holidays in /var/www/visitwembley.co.uk/development/getxmldata.php on line 33 Warning: XMLReader::read(): ^ in /var/www/visitwembley.co.uk/development/getxmldata.php on line 33 Warning: XMLReader::read(): An Error Occured while reading in /var/www/visitwembley.co.uk/development/getxmldata.php on line 33

Comment: Then your XML is malformed. `Travel & Holidays` should be `Travel &amp; Holidays` I think.

Comment: but this XML file is generated at third party so how can I change this ? any other code to change this ?

Comment: Notice: XMLReader::expand(): Cannot expand this node type in /var/www/visitwembley.co.uk/development/getxmldata.php on line 41 Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to DOMNode::appendChild() must be an instance of DOMNode, boolean given in /var/www/visitwembley.co.uk/development/getxmldata.php on line 43

Comment: If the file is not too big you could load the whole XML using SimpleXML. That would also eliminate the need for DOMDocument.